# How to play a video on the default media player on Windows?

Tags: asp.net

Here is the scenario: When you click on the image on homepage, the video should open. It should not be embedded video in a browser. Video should open in a default player. No browser window.

I have a static image on my homepage. When i click this image, i just require the video to run on the default player. The video file is located on the server.

Is it possible or not? And if possible then how can we achieve it?

Comment: Although, this can be done simply via using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting proper HTTP headers that enforce to download & open given video?

```
Content-Type: application/force-download
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="video.avi"
```

Comment: Yes this has to do with the servers MIME handling of this file extension. You need to make sure the HTTP response to the client is correctly representing it as a downloadable file.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need to use the `*.avi` extension at the end of your file, and place it on a link.

Now, the behavior will be different on each computer. The browser will ask the user to save the file somewhere and then if the user click on it will be open with the default player. Or in some cases it may direct ash him to open it with the default player, the browser saves it and then play it.

Now so good user interface.

Comment: Is it essential to have the *.avi extension? Please exlplain.

Comment: @Maxood The extension *.avi is the key because is the most possible that the windows have associate with them the player. To be aple to play any video must have the correct codec installed. I do not know if the mp4 format is one of the default formats on the windows vista and up. You need to test it. The mp4 can still be end in .avi

Comment: That is something the user's machine should have! I appreciate your comment. But the original question is about the functionality. What do you mean when you said "The mp4 can still be end in .avi" ?